# SelectOneMenu don't load the options on init

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a dropdown `<p:selectOneMenu>`, but not load on init page.

I took this example in Primefaces Showcase. I don't think anything is wrong in this code. I have getters and setters, initialized the options list.

My Init in controller class:

```
  @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        options = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            options.add("Option " + i);
        }
    } /*...*/
    public String getOption() {
    return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public List<String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
```

My xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="cont_principal">
        <h:inputHidden id="hidenOcr" value="/RESOURCES/images/home/arteris.png"/>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 0.4%;">

                <h:form>
                    <p:outputLabel for="lazy" value="Lazy:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="lazy" value="#{pagIni.option}" dynamic="true" style="width:125px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{pagIni.options}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:panelGrid id="telas1" class="col-md-3"
                        style="margin:5px; font-size: 10px;min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px; width: 25%;">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column colspan="2">Dados veículos</p:column>
                            </p:row>

                        </f:facet>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">Serial: </p:column>
                            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">#{pagIni.serial}</p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
    <!-- 
did not fit all the code  -->

            </h:form>
        </div>      


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: so if you add a ' to string' of the options list and use that in a different getter in a plain jsf  ` h:outputText` you do see the content? and what if you run in jsf development mode

Comment: what kind of bean are you using? it might be a problem with you baking bean scope or annotation, please add the bean definition to the code @Leandro Kojima